# Want runtime polymorphism while using type parameter or generic?

Tags: scala, generics, polymorphism, abstract-type

The following is a story about "animal eats food", and there is a cat eating a fish.

```
class Food
abstract class Animal {
  type F
  def eat(food: F)
}
class Fish extends Food
class Cat extends Animal {
  type F = Fish
  def eat(fish: F) {
    println("eat " + fish.getClass.getSimpleName)
  }
}

(new Cat).eat(new Fish) //eat Fish

val animal: Animal = new Cat
animal.eat(new Fish) //error: type mismatch
```

Now that I have used abstract-type member (or type-parameter) , I **lose** the `runtime polymorphism` (at last line). (that using base type Animal to typing arbitrary subtypes and run with no problem.)

---

Otherwise I can remove the type parameter from Animal and type checking in Cat:

```
abstract class Animal {
  def eat(food: Food)
}
class Cat extends Animal {
  def eat(food: Food) {
    food match {
      case fish: Fish => println("eat" + fish)
      case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("I only eat fish")
    }
  }
}
```

But I want the better typing for them .
So can I preserve runtime polymorphism while using type-parameter / generic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now that I have used abstract-type member (or type-parameter) , I lose the runtime polymorphism (at last line). (that using base type Animal to typing arbitrary subtypes and run with no problem.)

No, you can replace `Animal` by its subtypes (in context like this, not always!), but not vice versa. If you could, you would be able to use `Object` as well, since it's also a base type of `Cat`:

```
val object: Object = new Cat
object.eat(new Fish)
```

Hopefully you see why this shouldn't compile.

Or you could put it another way: should

```
val animal: Animal = makeAnAnimal() 
animal.eat(new Fish)
```

compile? If you think the answer is "yes", consider that `makeAnAnimal()` could return a `Cow`.

Comment: Thanks. I get it. The generic code is right.  It has given the right semantic in such case, and more powerful typing than otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best approach but it seems to work. You can allow to pass any kind of food to an animal risking class cast exception and handling it if happens.

```
class Food
abstract class Animal {
  type SuitableFood <: Food
  def eat(food: SuitableFood)

  def eatWithExceptionHandling(food: Food) {
    try {
      eat(food.asInstanceOf[SuitableFood])
    }
    catch {
      case ex: ClassCastException => println("Wrong food")
    }
  }
}

class Grass extends Food
class Fish extends Food

class Cow extends Animal {
  type SuitableFood = Grass
  override def eat(food: Grass) {
    println("Cow eating grass")
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  type SuitableFood = Fish
  override def eat(food: Fish) {
    println("Cat eating fish")
  }
}

val (cow, cat, grass ,fish) = (new Cow, new Cat, new Grass, new Fish)

cow.eat(grass) //"Cow eating grass"
cat.eat(fish) //"Cat eating fish"
//cow.eat(fish) // error: type mismatch
cow.eatWithExceptionHandling(grass) //"Cow eating grass"
cow.eatWithExceptionHandling(fish) //"Wrong food"
```